# Get the matches of a pattern in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following regular expression:

```
^[[][A-Za-z_1-9]+[\]]$
```

I want to be able to get all the matches of this regular expression in a string. The match should be of the form `[Whatever]`. Inside the braces, there could also be an `_` or numeric characters. So I wrote the following code:

```
private const String REGEX = @"^[[][A-Za-z_1-9]+[\]]$"; 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String expression = "([ColumnName] * 500) / ([AnotherColumn] - 50)";

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(expression, REGEX);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But unfortunately, `matches` is always having a count of zero. Apparently, the regular expression is checking whether the whole String is a match and not getting the matches out of the string. I'm not sure whether the regular expression is wrong or the way I'm using `Regex.Matches()` is incorrect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide us with the input for the expression.

Comment: BTW, for simplicity's sake, you can use [`\[\w+\]`](http://ideone.com/o6c8T) (`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) (Unless you explicitly are exempting `0`, then of course nevermind [wasn't sure if it was a typo]. ;p)

Comment: Actually yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the start/end of string anchors (`^` and `$`) from your pattern, since the matches you are looking for are not actually at the start and end of the string. You can also just use `\[` and `\]` instead of `[[]` and `[\]]`:

```
private const String REGEX = @"\[[A-Za-z_1-9]+\]";
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

You're anchoring your regex to the beginning and end of the string so of course it won't match anything.

Removing the anchors (`^` for beginning and `$` for end) works fine:

```
[[][A-Za-z_1-9]+[\]]
```

It returns, as you would hopefully expect:

```
[ColumnName]
[AnotherColumn]
```